# SQL pattern matching in search conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a field `name`.

For a given name like `ABC` I want to get the records with that name and the records which have an `L` appended at the end.

So for `ABC` I want all records with name either `ABC` or `ABCL`.

I tried getting the records using the following code but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE name like "ABC[|L]"
```

I am using TSQL.

How can pattern match these names?

Comment: where name IN ('ABC','ABCL')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE name IN ('ABC', 'ABCL')
```

If you are using this SQL within a Stored Procedure / Function, something like following would work. Assuming, you are passing in the value for `name` in a `@name` variable.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE name IN (@name, @name + 'L')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `IN` operator.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl
WHERE name IN ('ABC', 'ABCL')
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you will be using variables instead of literal strings, try this:

```
select *
  from tbl
 where name like (@YourName + @ExtraLetter)
    or name = @YourName
```

Comment: Why did someone downvote working answer? https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/395645